# All primes for which $p! + p$ is perfect square

Tags: number-theory

Find all prime number $p$ for which $p! + p$ in a perfect square.

Of course $p=2$ and $p=3$ are solutions.

I think there are not other solutions, but I can’t prove it!

Comment: See [Art of Problem Solving](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h463557_pp_is_a_perfect_square).